# Reading Dates with two digit years in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to parse a date with 2 digit years. However this does not work. Can somebody please tell me why?

```
Browse[1]> as.Date("Jan-84", format = "%b-%y")
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **zoo** package is helpful for this:

```
require(zoo)

x <- as.yearmon("Jan-84", format = "%b-%y")
```

The lines above first convert the input to class yearmon:

```
"Jan 1984"
```

From there you can convert the yearmon class to Date (or POSIXct), like this:

```
x <– as.Date(x)
```

Now the object is of class Date:

```
"1984-01-01"
```